# Strange lines on screen and systems hangs

Tags: memory, graphics-card, motherboard, dell-vostro

I have a pretty old laptop from 2010 (Dell Vostro 1015). I was using Windows 7 on it till last year. It developed some hardware issue last year and I got it repaired but could not use it for few months. Now I thought to use it for my git repository and install ubuntu on it. When I start it in windows 7 or try to install ubuntu, it gives me strange lines on screen and hangs. No key works in this case and I have to hard-reset the system each time.

This does not happen everytime, it happens intermittently. Sometimes system would work for hours without this issue, sometimes I would get this problem after 5 minutes of running it. I am attaching a picture of the strange lines.

Please suggest what could be issue. Please let me know what other information would you need.
[image]

Comment: The issue is hardware failure (graphics).

Comment: Thank you @MichaelBay for quick response. I will check it further and update here my findings.

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely that your hardware is failing or overheating. Normally I'd recommend to try to see if the problem also occurs using a different operating system to rule out driver related issues but you've already confirmed this.

Now, your graphics controller is integrated into the chipset (Intel G45). If it was overheating, I'd expect you to have other issues as well. The graphics controller uses the system memory as video memory so I'd recommend to try the following things (in this order):

1. Run a memory test on your computer (e.g. Memtest86+). Leave it running for multiple passes
2. Try connecting an external monitor. If the external monitor doesn't have any issues while the laptop's display does, it is likely the screen or the cable to the screen is faulty.
3. Open up the laptop and clean out any dust from the cooling system
4. Disassemble the cooling system and reapply thermal paste
5. Replace motherboard :)